# Poloniex api error - Invalid API key/secret pair

Tags: php, api, poloniex

I'm using the Poloniex PHP wrapper yet I can't seem to get it to accept my keys without throwing an error.

Poloniex PHP Wrapper:
https://pastebin.com/iuezwGRZ

For fast tests I use the following code:

```
<?php
include('poloniex.php');
$poloniex_key = 'mykey';  
$poloniex_secret = 'mysecretkey';
$poloniex = new poloniex($poloniex_key, $poloniex_secret);
$balance = $poloniex->get_balances();
print_r($balance);
?>
```

Returns:
Invalid API key/secret pair.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a API key/secret for your own account.
First login into poloniex account, then go to [api setup page](https://poloniex.com/apiKeys)
Then click "Create New Keys"

After done, replace 'mykey' and 'mysecretkey' by what poloniex give you in your code:

```
$poloniex_key = '...';  
$poloniex_secret = '...';
```